# how to clearly design these two class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
        interface ILife {
            void Equip(IWeapon weapon);
        }
        interface IWeapon {
            void OnEquip(ILife life);
        }
        class People : ILife {
            int nowPower;
            public void Equip(IWeapon weapon) {
                //do something.....
                weapon.OnEquip(this);
                //so how to do like nowPower+=weapon.addPower?
            }
        }
        class Weapon : IWeapon {
            ILife user;
            int addPower=200;
            public void OnEquip(ILife life) {
                user = life;
                //do something...
            }
        }
```

here is my code in the game,there are many field like addPower in Weapon need to be deal in ILife, so how can i DO that without adding fields in interface IWeapon to keep code clean and great?

sry i'm new in stackoverflow. the reason why i don't choose language is i just want to talk about design not code.

Comment: Why the tag-spamming? Which language are you devloping in? Those are pretty different when it comes to interfaces and their implementation. Which makes this question impossible to answer.

Comment: From the three, it's clearly C#, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it's still tag spam

Comment: @churill Seems so. But I would let OP clearify it instead of guessing. Might even be pseudeo-code or any of the not-tagged languages.

Comment: sry i'm new in stackoverflow. the reason why i don't choose language is i just want to talk about design not code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question of design. `Weapon` has the field `addPower`, but `IWeapon` does not. This would imply, that not all weapons (not all classes that implement `IWeapon`) do add power to the character. So you can't use this property, if the interface doesn't define it. (Casting an interface to an implementing class defies the whole point of using an interface in the first place)

If *all* weapons can add power, then the interface `IWeapon` needs to reflect this requirement of a weapon:

```
interface IWeapon {
    void OnEquip(ILife life);

    int AddPower { get; }
}
```

Then all weapons need to implement this property:

```
class Weapon : IWeapon {
    int addPower=200;

    public int AddPower 
    {
        get {
            return this.addPower;
        }
    }
}
```

If a weapon does *not* add any power (e.g. defensive equipment) it might as well return 0 in `AddPower`, makes no difference.

Comment: thanks you churill